# Code not working when migrated into function : "Uncaught ReferenceError: svg is not defined"?

Tags: javascript

My former code works fine, in linear order :

```
// SVG injection:
var width  = 600;
var svg = d3.select("#hook").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width);

// Projection default
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .scale(1)
        .translate([0, 0]);
var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection); //  .pointRadius(4)

injectPattern();
```

...but I want to migrate it into a function with multipe parameters. When I do the move into a function such :

```
var locationMap = function(hookId, width, target, title, WEST, NORTH, EAST, SOUTH){
    // all previous code and more here
}
locationMap(all_the_suitable_parameters_here)
```

it fails, now returning for `injectPattern()` the error message :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: svg is not defined
```

Note, injectPattern() indeed append some content to `svg`, but it formerly did it after the svg was create.

```
var injectPattern = function(){
    var pattern = svg.append("defs")
        .append("pattern")
            .attr({ id:"hash2_4", width:"6", height:"6", patternUnits:"userSpaceOnUse", patternTransform:"rotate(-45)"})
        .append("rect")
            .attr({ width:"2", height:"6", transform:"translate(0,0)", fill:"#E0E0E0" }); // (!) fill: wp.location.land
}
```

**How to migrate my code to a function yet to keep it working it the same former and correct order ?**

[Working but not into function](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/1.2_location_map/index.html) VS [into function but sending error back](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/1.2_location_map/index_bug.html)

Comment: because svg is a local variable in your function locationMap now? so svg is unknown in injectPattern function.

Comment: But injectPattern() is local as well, It doesn't get things at same level as itself ? ⁰__⁰

Comment: u mean injectPattern function is in locationMap function ?

Comment: Correct, but I'am still new to JS

Comment: @Cracker0dks: ok, I'am digging in. Starts to work. thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will not work:

```
function locationMap() { 
    var svg = .... //Svg is only visible in locationMap function
}

function injectPattern() {
    use svg here;
}
```

---

this will work but is not nice:

```
function locationMap() { 
    var svg = .... 
    function injectPattern() {
        use svg here; //will work
    }
}
```

you dont have to use a function if you call it once...

### **EDIT:**

if you must have a function you can pass your svg as a paramenter:

```
function locationMap() { 
    svg = ....
    injectPattern(svg);
}

function injectPattern(svg) {
        use svg here; //will work
}
```

clean way with function.